# How do I create an Ender Portal using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I create an Ender Portal without using mods and plug-ins? Can I use `/summon` to get one? Or what command should I use?

I want to get a block which is placeable or directly place a block using commands, in Creative Mode.

Comment: Have you checked if you can /give yourself the items you need to build it and then construct it by hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The portal is nothing else than a block, and blocks have IDs. So, as mentioned in the comment  before, you can use `/give` to get the blocks and build it.

Use this command to get a enderportalblock and the frames with endereyes:

```
/give player 119 9 
/give player 120 5 4
/give player 120 5 5
/give player 120 3 6
/give player 120 3 7
```

A little explanation: Block 119 is the portalblock. Basically, this is enough to get into the end. But to make it look like a realistic ender portal, you need 9 of them. Around the portalblocks you need the stones with the endereyes. The block ID is 120 and with the Meta-ID, you can set additional properties for them. 0 - 3 defines the direction in which the block is facing and NO endereye, while 4 - 7 does the same, just that these blocks already contain an endereye. You can only activate a portal if all outer blocks are facing each other, but since you use console commands, it doesnt really matter and you can also use `/give player 120 16 4`.

Im not completely sure if these commands work, i dont have minecraft on this PC here, if not, i will edit it as soon as im at home ... so in 8 hours or something. :P

Comment: Note that when Minecraft 1.8 is released, item ids that use numbers will not work anymore.

Comment: The corresponding names would be 199 = end_portal, 120 = end_portal_frame. For 120 you will need to add the metadata tags to indicate the eyes are in the frame.

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~2 end_portal
```

or, for a nether portal,

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~2 portal
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can activate the End Portal using the /summon Command as /summon is only for Entities. It is better to use /give to give yourself End Portals and place them. Other ideas are:

2. Go to Creative and place them or
3. Use Setblock Command

Answer (score -1):

In survival, with no commands, you can't create one. You have to find an underground stronghold, find the end portal, and use ender eyes. Only then can you get to the End.